# How do I convert an image to a base64-encoded data URL in sails.js or generally in the servers side JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I am making a small app in `sails.js` and I need to store images in database. For that, I need to convert an image to a base64-encoded data URL so that I can save it as a string in my sails models. However, I don't know how to convert it in this form. All the older questions asked about converting an image to base64-encoded data URLs, and they answer this about doing it on the client side.  However, I want to do it on the server side while I will be getting the image through a post request.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: What's your sever side technology?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

As I understand you want to convert a file into base64 encoded string. Whether the file is image or not, that does not matter.

```
var fs = require('fs');

// function to encode file data to base64 encoded string
function base64_encode(file) {
    // read binary data
    var bitmap = fs.readFileSync(file);
    // convert binary data to base64 encoded string
    return new Buffer(bitmap).toString('base64');
}
```

Usage:

```
var base64str = base64_encode('kitten.jpg');
```

[Source](http://www.hacksparrow.com/base64-encoding-decoding-in-node-js.html)

Comment: `fs.readFile` gives a buffer if no encoding is passed, so no need for the `new Buffer()`. [Related doc](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback).

Comment: Don't forget to add the data URI prefix: `data:[<mediatype>][;base64],` For example: `data:image/png;base64,` in case of a PNG image. More info: [Data URIs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs)

Comment: new Buffer() is deprecated. You can use instead fs.readFileSync(file, { encoding: 'base64' });

Comment: base64 encoded only is free, but to create a dataURI, some kind of mime-db is required. https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime-types

Answer (score 114):

It can be achieved with **readFileSync**, passing in the image path as the first parameter and an encoding option as the second. As show below:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var imageAsBase64 = fs.readFileSync('./your-image.png', 'base64');
```

As per the [node](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) documentation:

> **fs.readFileSync(path[, options])**
>
> Synchronous version of fs.readFile(). Returns the
>   contents of the path.
>
> If the encoding option is specified then this function returns a
>   string. Otherwise it returns a buffer.

Comment: @JSON-C11 Why not use the async version of this?

Comment: I am trying to use it in angular and  getting an error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'

Comment: what if I have a URL instead of a file...

Comment: you can also import a promisify version of `fs` like this `import fs from 'fs/promises';`

Answer (score 2):

//You can use the image-to-base64

```
const imageToBase64 = require('image-to-base64');

imageToBase64("URL") // insert image url here. 
    .then( (response) => {
          console.log(response);  // the response will be the string base64.
      }
    )
    .catch(
        (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

### Another solution to use the `Buffer.from`

1. `ES6` version

```js
import fs from 'node:fs';

const convertImageToBase64URL = (filename, imageType = 'png') => {
  try {
    const buffer = fs.readFileSync(filename);
    const base64String = Buffer.from(buffer).toString('base64');
    // console.log(`base64String`, base64String.slice(0, 100));
    return `data:image/${imageType};base64,${base64String}`;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(`file ${filename} no exist ❌`)
  }
}

export {
  convertImageToBase64URL,
};

// test cases
const ok = convertImageToBase64URL("./public/test.png");
const err = convertImageToBase64URL();
```

2. `TypeScript` version

```
import fs from 'node:fs';

type Filename = string;
type ImageType = 'png' | 'jpg' | 'jpeg' | 'gif' | 'webp';
type Base64String = `data:image/${ImageType};base64,${string}`;

const convertImageToBase64URL = (filename: Filename, imageType: ImageType = 'png'): Base64String => {
  try {
    const buffer = fs.readFileSync(filename);
    const base64String = Buffer.from(buffer).toString('base64');
    // console.log(`base64String`, base64String.slice(0, 100));
    return `data:image/${imageType};base64,${base64String}`;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(`file ${filename} no exist ❌`)
  }
}

export {
  convertImageToBase64URL,
};

// test cases
const ok = convertImageToBase64URL("./public/test.png");
const err = convertImageToBase64URL();
/* 

Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)
An argument for 'filename' was not provided.
const convertImageToBase64URL: (filename: Filename, imageType?: ImageType) => Base64String

*/
```

### refs

https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#static-method-bufferfrombuffer

Answer (score -3):

```
//instala via npm
npm install --save image-to-uri

//declara no codigo
const imageToUri = require('image-to-uri');

//implementa 
let imagem = imageToUri("caminho da sua imagem");
```

Answer (score -14):

Here`s another simple way, use it when listing your images

```
@{
    if (item.ImageData != null)
    {
        string imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(item.ImageData);
        string imageSrc = string.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", imageBase64);
        <img src="@imageSrc" width="100" height="100" />
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is javascript at all

Comment: Razor syntax after all

Comment: excuse me, this question is about JS, not C# or ASP.NET.

Comment: This looks like C#, The question is asking for Javascript