# How to get base64 content of the image from URL using node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an image url : Lets say,

https://www.bing.com/th?id=OHR.PontadaPiedade_FR-FR0880264205_1920x1080.jpg&rf=LaDigue_1920x1080.jpg&pid=hp

Requirement :

I need to create an image file in my repository or i need base64 content of that image.

Comment: Probably duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523532/how-do-i-convert-an-image-to-a-base64-encoded-data-url-in-sails-js-or-generally

Comment: @AmolBJamkar The given link is converting the data from local file.

Comment: this might help you then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17124053/node-js-get-image-from-web-and-encode-with-base64/17133012

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert image into base64 string using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js get image from web and encode with base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17124053/node-js-get-image-from-web-and-encode-with-base64)