# how to upload image in mongodb using node js under a specific model

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am working on a project (Something like a shopping website) and I want to upload a product describing its name, price and image. It's pretty simple to add name, price in a database, but not finding a proper way to have all those information along with a product Image as there is no specific way to store image like we store Strings and Numbers etc. I do not want to upload a file locally with a package called multer. I have tried using Grid FS storage, but I do not  how to make it keep all three information together as a single package. I am looking for a better way so I could use it when I will make my website live.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert an image to a base64 encoded string. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523532/how-do-i-convert-an-image-to-a-base64-encoded-data-url-in-sails-js-or-generally) for more information. Also see [this npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64-img).

But be careful! As far as I know MongoDB has a maximum storage size for a document. If you plan to save a couple high-res images in that document you will go better with a file storage.